# JobCancellationException UndispatchedCoroutine error in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm still new to coroutines (but already love them lots). I've got this error (and crash) and not sure what it means. What is an UndispatchedCoroutine? how it gets cancelled?

> kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: UndispatchedCoroutine was cancelled; job="coroutine#8":UndispatchedCoroutine{Cancelled}@fe7d397

Edit:
To give some context, I'm using an Actor to execute the handling of the message in a coroutine:

```
@OptIn(kotlinx.coroutines.ObsoleteCoroutinesApi::class)
internal inner class HandlerFPMsg : Handler() {
    private val msgActor = coroutineScope.actor<Pair<Int, Long>>(Dispatchers.Default, capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED) {
        for(msg in channel)
            handleMessageWorker(msg.first, msg.second)
    }

    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        msgActor.offer(Pair(msg.what, msg.data.getLong("ID",-1L)))
        super.handleMessage(msg)
    }

    private suspend fun handleMessageWorker(what: Int, id: Long) {
        if (what != 0x92) Log.d("Messenger123", "Message Received: [" + what.toString(16) + "]")
        when (what) {
            MsgConstants.MSG_CONSTANT1 -> {
                someFunction()
                Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
            }
            MsgConstants.MSG_CONSTANT2 -> {
                if (id != lastId) return
                // -----------------------
                if (aSuspendingFunction()) {
                    msgService?.let { msgr -> aClass.sendAmsg(msgr) }
                } else {
                    // some comment 
                    someFunction()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if i wrap `handleMessageWorker(msg.first, msg.second)` with a try catch block seems to work (but i don't know how correct would be the code...)

Comment: Undispatched coroutine is a state when you can nested context on the same dispatcher, which is not an problem by itself. What exactly your code does?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a definitive answer, but I find that comments are too short for that.

Judging by the fact that this is an inner class, and that you're creating your `actor` using `coroutineScope` from the outside, my guess would be that your `coroutineScope` gets terminated, which also terminates your actor. This is the correct behavior of structured concurrency.

Question is: why your coroutine scope gets terminated.

Two main possibilities:

1. It's bound to lifecycle of another object. If you're launching this actor from scope of an Android `Activity`, coroutineScope may get terminated once the activity closes.
2. Another piece of code that uses the same scope throws an exception. This will also cause scope to terminate, unless it's [supervisorScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html)

Comment: Definitely the 2nd, cause the coroutineScope i'm using is the one of a Service `MyService : LifecycleService()` so i get `lifecycleScope` from it and the service is up and running (foreground service started with startService and bound). But I can't understand what's really triggering the exception from the stacktrace i get with the option `System.setProperty(DEBUG_PROPERTY_NAME, DEBUG_PROPERTY_VALUE_ON)`

Comment: I would suggest trying `supervisorScope`, to see if you get any stack trances you may be missing otherwise.